# How to convert from RedirectMatch to RewriteRule and remove the query string

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert from rewritematch to RewriteRule and remove the query string. Example:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/(.*)/old-path/$   /$1/new-path/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/old-path/?$ /$1/new-path/? [L,NC,R=301]
```